# How to calculate the infinite value of a division?

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know the repeating decimal in a fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946310/how-to-know-the-repeating-decimal-in-a-fraction)

1/3 is different by 3/10. 0.33333 != 0.3

So 1/3 will be 0.3 (with a line above number three)

1/12 = 0.833333 = 0.083 (with a line above number three)

1/13 = 0.076923076923 = 0.|076923|

Those lines represent the repeating part.

I plan to have this model in a class. I'm a bit lost on this situation. I just need some ideas to know determine the repeating value. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, emulate long division.  Keep track of every long division remainder.  If you encounter a remainder you have seen before, the sequence since you saw that remainder is the repeating value.

Comment: Although it is duplicate, no one ever mentions about cycle finding algorithm in the duplicate question, though.

Answer (score 5):

[Cycle detection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) is the answer. You can use [Floyd's cycle detection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) or [Brent's cycle detection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Brent.27s_algorithm).

The function to plug into those algorithms is the function to produce the next digit of the quotient.

Answer (score 4):

At each step, divide, floor, take the remainder, multiply that by ten, repeat until you get the same number.

For example, for 1/81:

```
1/81 = 0 with remainder 1       0
10/81 = 0 with remainder 10     0.0
100/81 = 1 with remainder 19    0.01
190/81 = 2 with remainder 28    0.012
280/81 = 3 with remainder 37    0.0123
...
10/81 = 0 with remainder 10; saw this already.
0.|012345679|
```

Here's a sample implementation:

```
private static string GetRepeatingPart(int n, int d) {
    var seen = new HashSet<int>();
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    n = (n % d) * 10;

    while(true) {
        int p = n / d;
        n = (n % d) * 10;

        if(seen.Contains(n)) {
            return result.ToString();
        }

        result.Append(p);
        seen.Add(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a correct method, with space complexity of O(lambda + mu) and lower hidden constant for time complexity, compared to O(1) space and higher hidden constant for time complexity of cycle finding algorithm.