# How to know if a number is irrational (infinite)

Tags: php, numbers, infinity

I've created a function who check if a number is irrational or not:

```
function Verifie_infini($value) {
    if(strlen(substr(strrchr($value, "."), 1))>= 10) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when there are big numbers like: `sqrt(1194739201)` it return `0`.
Have you an idea or do exist a better function?

Comment: PHP already has an [is_infinite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-infinite.php) function that actually works. `if (is_infinite($value)) ....`

Comment: By "infinite" you probably mean numbers whose decimal representations are infinite, i.e. irrational numbers. I don't think this is doable, because floating point arithmetics works with rational approximations and have no notion of irrationals.

Comment: Yes I would say irrational numbers (sorry for my english). I thought count decimals to suggest if it's an irrational or not number.

Comment: @louis67: yes, and that's not possible (think: how can you _count_ an _infinite_ number?)

Comment: @georg Yes I would check if the number has more that 10 decimals for example and then say that's irrationnal. My function work for small and medium numbers but after it doesn't work.

Comment: @louis67: ok, can you explain what you're trying to do? What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: @georg : I've created a PHP page to calculate a trinomial equation **ax²+bx+c**. And I would to show the result **x1** and **x2** with the perfect result (not a rounding value). So if the result is `(sqrt(2))/4` the program will stop and don't show the rounded value as the perfect result because he know that `(sqrt(2))/4` is not a finite number (irrational)

Comment: @louis67: I see. Answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments above, you're looking for a way to calculate mathematically exact square roots. This problem belongs to the domain of [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) and cannot be solved with floating-point manipulations. Here's a (deliberately simplified) example of how to take a square root symbolically:

```
function factorize($n) {
    $factors = array();
    $p = 2;
    while($n > 1) {
        if($n % $p == 0) {
            $factors[$p]++;
            $n = intval($n / $p);
        } else $p++;
    }
    return $factors;
}

function symbolic_root($n) {
    $rat = $irr = 1;
    foreach(factorize($n) as $prime => $power) {
        $rat *= pow($prime, intval($power / 2));
        $irr *= pow($prime, intval($power % 2));
    }
    if($irr == 1) return $rat;
    if($rat == 1) return "sqrt $irr";    
    return "$rat * sqrt($irr)";
}

echo symbolic_root(1522756), "\n"; # prints "1234"
echo symbolic_root(5549544), "\n"; # prints "462 * sqrt(26)"
```

Explanation for those curious:

First, we factor the number into the prime powers:

> 5549544 = 2<sup>3</sup>×3<sup>2</sup>×7<sup>2</sup>×11<sup>2</sup>×13<sup>1</sup>

then, divide each power by two, which gives us the rational part of the root:

> 462 = 2<sup>1</sup>×3<sup>1</sup>×7<sup>1</sup>×11<sup>1</sup>×13<sup>0</sup>

and the rests (1s and 0s) form the irrational part

> 26 = 2<sup>1</sup>×3<sup>0</sup>×7<sup>0</sup>×11<sup>0</sup>×13<sup>1</sup>

Comment: I've not all understood but it's exactly what I'm looking for ! Now I will try to find a function to determinate if a fraction can be decimal or not (ex : 1/3 is not decimal)

Comment: @louis67:  see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946310/how-to-know-the-repeating-decimal-in-a-fraction. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

#### [is_infinite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-infinite.php)

> Returns TRUE if val is infinite (positive or negative), like the
> result of log(0) or any value too big to fit into a float on this
> platform.

```
if(is_infinite($number))
{
  #your code
}
```

Comment: Yes but if I use this function with `sqrt(2)` for example it returns that's not infinite.